# javascript sort by nearest start date time to present to furthest away and another attribute

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have to do a sorting by start date time with a reference to current date time with multiple attributes. 
For ex, I have this list:

```
<ul>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=false>Name1</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:30" data-inplay=false>Name2</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:20" data-inplay=false>Name3</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 16:00" data-inplay=false>Name4</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=true> Name5</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:10" data-inplay=false>Name6</li>
    <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:05" data-inplay=true> Name7</li>
    <li data-startDate="08-04-2019 12:05" data-inplay=false>Name8</li>
</ul>
```

and the current date time is 09-04-2019 15:15, the desired output should be:

```html
<!--
  Let currentDate = 09-04-2019 15:15
  Sort priority:
    1. inplay is true
    2. startDate is greater than currentDate
    3. startDate is lesser than currentDate
-->
<ul>
  <!-- inplay == true -->
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:05" data-inplay=true>Name7</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=true>Name5</li>

  <!-- startDate > currentDate -->
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:20" data-inplay=false>Name3</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:30" data-inplay=false>Name2</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 16:00" data-inplay=false>Name4</li>

  <!-- startDate < currentDate -->
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:10" data-inplay=false>Name6</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=false>Name1</li>
  <li data-startDate="08-04-2019 12:05" data-inplay=false>Name8</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this but doesn't include inplay param and also the ordering is not quite correct

```
var list = $("ul > li");
var target = new Date().getTime();
var sortByStartTime = function (a, b) {
    var ret = 0;
    var startDateA = $(a).data("startdate");
    var startDateB = $(b).data("startdate");
    var dateA = startDateA.split(" ")[0].split("-");
    var timeA = startDateA.split(" ")[1].split(":");
    var dateB = startDateB.split(" ")[0].split("-");
    var timeB = startDateB.split(" ")[1].split(":");
    startDateA = new Date(dateA[2], dateA[1] - 1, dateA[0], timeA[0], timeA[1]);
    startDateB = new Date(dateB[2], dateB[1] - 1, dateB[0], timeB[0], timeB[1]);
    var dA = Math.abs(startDateA.getTime() - target);
    var dB = Math.abs(startDateB.getTime() - target);
    if (dA < dB) {
        ret = -1;
    } else if (dA > dB) {
        ret = 1;
    }  else {
        ret = 0;
    }
    return ret;
};

list.sort(sortByStartTime);

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i = i + 1) {
    list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
}
```

Basically the list should be ordered by nearest start date time (relative to current date time) to furthest, but if there are some inplay they should be at the top of the list ordered by nearest start date time (relative to current date time) to furthest. I hope I explain clear enough.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: hi @Bogdan - your requirement or explanation of it little inaccurate. i see sort by inplay attr and sort by startdatetime, but i see 2 sets of inplay of false with some randomly sorted datetime. could you please explain.

Comment: Hi @user2648008 got a response that is working, thanks for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sort logic:**

1. Sort by data inplay true or false, using number to simplify the sort logic (sort in descending order)
2. If the differences are on opposite
   side of zero keep positive value first and negative value later
   (sort in descending order)
3. If the difference to current time
   for both the dates are on the same side of 0, sort by their absolute
   values (sort in ascending order)

```js
var list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li"));
var target = new Date('09-04-2019 15:15');
var boolValue = { true: 1, false: 0 };
var sortByStartTime = function (a, b) {
    var diffA = new Date(a.dataset.startdate) - target;
    var diffB = new Date(b.dataset.startdate) - target;
    var inplayA = boolValue[a.dataset.inplay];
    var inplayB = boolValue[b.dataset.inplay];
    return inplayB - inplayA || (
        diffA < 0 === diffB < 0 ? Math.abs(diffA) - Math.abs(diffB) : diffB - diffA
    );
};

list.sort(sortByStartTime);

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i = i + 1) {
    list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=false>Name1</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:30" data-inplay=false>Name2</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:20" data-inplay=false>Name3</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 16:00" data-inplay=false>Name4</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=true> Name5</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:10" data-inplay=false>Name6</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:05" data-inplay=true> Name7</li>
  <li data-startDate="08-04-2019 12:05" data-inplay=false>Name8</li>
</ul>
```

> **PS:** replace `new Date('09-04-2019 15:15');` with `new Date();` to get what you wanted. I hardcoded the date to show that results are as per your requirement.

Comment: Your output is not the same as the desired output

Comment: Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do get the `lis` elements like an array using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...document.querySelectorAll('li')]`

Then create `lisSorted` that is going to contain an array of elements sorted by the element attribute `data-startDate` and by the boolean attribute `data-inplay`

Code:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const lis = [...ul.querySelectorAll('li')];
const lisSorted = lis
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const x = a.getAttribute('data-inplay');
    const y = b.getAttribute('data-inplay');
    return ((x === y) ? 0 : x ? -1 : 1) || new Date(b.getAttribute('data-startDate')) - new Date(a.getAttribute('data-startDate'));
  });

ul.append(...lisSorted);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=false>Name1</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:30" data-inplay=false>Name2</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:20" data-inplay=false>Name3</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 16:00" data-inplay=false>Name4</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:00" data-inplay=true> Name5</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:10" data-inplay=false>Name6</li>
  <li data-startDate="09-04-2019 15:05" data-inplay=true> Name7</li>
  <li data-startDate="08-04-2019 12:05" data-inplay=false>Name8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the `data-inplay` attribute. If true they should come before all other results.

Comment: @Mathyn Thank you for the comment.. Updated answer